# Mark multiple locations on google maps?

Tags: maps

I have this code copied from another post from stackoverflow, I don't have any experience with the google maps api.

```
    <html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<meta name="generator" content="CoffeeCup HTML Editor (www.coffeecup.com)">

<meta name="dcterms.created" content="Tue, 08 Jan 2013 05:31:17 GMT">
    <meta name="description" content="">

<meta name="keywords" content="">

<title></title>

<script
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDY0kkJiTPVd2U7aTOAwhc9ySH6oHxOIYM&sensor=false">
</script>

<script>

var geocoder, map;

function initialize() {

geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(100, 100);

var myOptions = {
    zoom:5,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

codeAddress();

}


function codeAddress() {

var address = "Bucuresti, Romania";
var address = "Galati, Romania";

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

map: map, 

position: results[0].geometry.location
      });

} 
else {

alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

</script>

</head>

<body onload="initialize()">
 <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 720px; height: 480px;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

The map will only show Bucharest as marked, how can I make it display both cities as marked.

Answer (score 0):

Pass address as parameter to codeAdress and call it as many address that you have. 
Currently it is only considering address[0]